# does razor page have onLoad method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I know there is get and post method in razor page but what if you want you load some code soon as page is loads up? do I use a **constructor** method?

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(){
           return Page();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to use depedency injection?If so,you can try to use a constructor method.Firstly,you need  to register a service in Program.cs,and then use a constructor in your pagemodel.

ICommentService:

```
public interface ICommentService
    {
        string Test();
    }
```

CommentService:

```
public class CommentService : ICommentService
    {
        public string Test()
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
```

pageModel:

```
public class TestdModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ICommentService _commentService;
        public TestdModel (ICommentService commentService)
        {
            _commentService = commentService;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use `_commentService` in your pagemodel.